# Hiding track image

Tags: iphone, ios

In my project am having three tracks Track1, Track2 and Track3,
And on the 3(tracks) of them one slider image(this is UIImageView but not UISlider)) is moving from left to right(by using timer).And also on the top right of the screen am having two buttons to save and share.When we click on share button another view(shareView) is appearing (which is 3/4th part of mainView) with options like Facebook, twitter..... on the present view.
But my problem is when we click on share button the slider is not hiding, it is also visible on shareView also. I want to hide that slider image(UIImageView).

Any one can help or suggest
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView inherits from the UIView class, which has [a hidden property.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) I imagine there are other ways to do this but using the hidden property should work. Set the hidden property to YES just prior to shareView appearing and then set it back to NO when shareView is dismissed.

```
imageView.hidden = YES;
```

OR

```
imageView.hidden = NO;
```

You might also want to try [the removeFromSuperview method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview), though you would also have to add it back into the same spot when you dismiss shareView.